# Ruby working with log times

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to detect multiple log entries within a given timeframe. I want ruby to be able to pick out every instance of a particular event within a given time range. so I have

```
12:42:32 user1 "foo'd a bar"
12:42:43 user1 "foo'd a bar"
12:43:02 user1 "foo'd a bar"
12:43:12 user8 "something else happened"
12:43:14 user1 "potato"
18:43:12 user2 "potato"
```

..within an array, and I want ruby to point out that  user1 "foo'd a bar" 3 times within 2 minutes (shocking!) and then do something else, like add the user name and time to a list or something.

Comment: Additional details are needed to propose a good solution (how to handle a four minute long period of matching events, are you looking for single or multiple triggering events). Showing us what you've tried would also be helpful.

Comment: basically i'm working on a way of analyzing server logs and highlighting points of interest for an admin.
I want ruby to look at a number of logs and pick out any IP addresses that look at a number of web addresses over a short time. 
So, to sudo:
  if IP address visits a number of addresses within a set range of time, record it.
I have been looking at ways of working on it all day, but I can't find anything....

Comment: I need a way of looking at a number of time's, for example 12:15:40(hour:min:sec respectively), 12:15:49, 12:16:02, and being able to ascertain how much time has passed, and if it's under that time...
not sure if that makes any sense, please say if it doesn't

Comment: ok, update. I'm messing with Time.new to help me with my conundrum. I may be in with a chance of figuring this out soon!

initially i'm going to (try) take the values from the times of the logs, throw them at Time.now and see what comes out of the other side!

Comment: Instead of attempting to roll your own log aggregation, parsing, searching and analysis tool, have you looked at some of the existing (commercial and non-commercial) solutions? Examples of such including [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/), [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/), and [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) (Logstash is often paired Elasticsearch and Kibana as the "ELK stack"). As a Splunk customer, I can safely say this is a fairly easy task in Splunk (a few different ways of doing it, with different tradeoffs), but it's probably just as easy in the others as well.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but this is part of an assignment :)